# Method not found at run time

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I use the org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToByteArray method in myAndroid application. I imported the jar file and I see this method is in my project. (I use Eclipse.) Actually, compilation is ok. Here's the message from LogCat:

```
01-26 18:43:08.177: I/dalvikvm(897): Could not find method org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToByteArray, referenced from method com.example.anagrams.MainActivity.readFile
```

So this is not an error, but then I get a NullPointerException due, apparently, to the statement:

```
private Button button_read_file = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_readfile);
```

I have no idea how to correct the NullPointerException. Also I am puzzled by the message about the method not found. The application is supposed to read a text file containing English words and then for each word to find all the anagrams that exist. For the moment I just use System.out.println to write the anagrams.

Any help is welcome. Following is my whole MainActivity (the only one so far):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private String[] words;
private Button button_read_file = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_readfile);
private EditText input_file_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1) ;
private Button button_write_file = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_writefile);    
private EditText output_file_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2) ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button_read_file.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String inputFileName = input_file_name.getText().toString();
            try {
            words = readFile(inputFileName, Charset.defaultCharset());
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.getStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.getStackTrace();
            }
        }});

    button_write_file.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; ++i) {
            String s = words[i];
            System.out.println(" words[" + i + "] = " + s);
            HashSet<String> a = new HashSet<String>();
            permutations(s,a);
                Iterator<String> iterator = a.iterator();
                while(iterator.hasNext()) {
                    System.out.println(iterator.next());
                }
        }
        }});
}

public String[] readFile(String path, Charset encoding) throws IOException {                                                                                                                                              
    File file = new File(path);
    byte[] encoded = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);
    String s = encoding.decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(encoded)).toString();
    s = s.replace(" ","");
    return s.split("[,.\\n\\s]");                                                                                                  
}                  

public ArrayList<String> getDictionary(String filename) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
    ArrayList<String> dictionary = new ArrayList<String>();
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(filename);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    String line = null;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        dictionary.add(line);
    }
    bufferedReader.close();
    return dictionary;
}

public boolean isInDictionary(String s) {
    String dictionaryname = "enable1.txt";
    ArrayList<String> dictionary = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
    dictionary = getDictionary(dictionaryname);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.getStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.getStackTrace();
    }
    if (dictionary.contains(s))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

public void permutations(String word, HashSet<String> anagrams) {
    generatePermutations("",word,anagrams);
}

public void generatePermutations(String prefix, String word, HashSet<String> anagrams) {
    int n = word.length();
    if (n == 0) {
        if (prefix != word && isInDictionary(prefix))
            anagrams.add(prefix);
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            generatePermutations(prefix + word.charAt(i),word.substring(0,i) + word.substring(i+1),anagrams);
        }
    }
}




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

And here's the layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_readfile"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:text="@string/read_file" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_writefile"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button_readfile"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button_readfile"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:text="@string/write_file" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_readfile"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_writefile"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />

</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button_writefile"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_writefile"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
    android:ems="10" >
</EditText>
```

Comment: Are you sure the buttons id you've included in your code is in the same layout?

Comment: Yes, in the same layout. There's only one layout file actually.

Comment: I've no experiences with android programming so far, so I'm a bit unaware of what `R` actually is - is it some kind of static class or singleton? As I do not see any initialization of it

Comment: R is a Java class generated automatically for each Android application.

Comment: and it is automatically injected into your class and it has a non-null id? As you indicated that the NPE is thrown on initializing the members, it seems that either `R` or `R.id` is null, else the NPE should have been thrown within the `findViewById(...)` method

Comment: I don't think either R or R.id is null. I did rename the package for this application, and I was trying to see if there's any problem with it. But I don't think there's any problem with renaming the package. Otherwise I could not compile the application.

Comment: Compiling the application has nothing to do with being able to execute your application :) Actually, the member variables are set when the object is initialized (before the content of the actual default constructor is executed). `onCreate(...)` is invoked afterwards by the android framework - at this time the initialization of the members has already long happened. And it seems that `R` is injected afterwards so it or its `id` is null at that time. Therefore stick to Aashir's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing these before the layout is even set:

```
private Button button_read_file = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_readfile);
private EditText input_file_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1) ;
private Button button_write_file = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_writefile);    
private EditText output_file_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2) ;
```

Change them to:

```
private Button button_read_file;
private EditText input_file_name;
private Button button_write_file;    
private EditText output_file_name;
```

Then declare them after setContentView(...) in your onCreate like:

```
button_read_file = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_readfile);
input_file_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1) ;
button_write_file = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_writefile);    
output_file_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2) ;
```

If you see `NoClassDefFoundError`, try this in Eclipse:

- Go to *Project Properties* → *Java Build Path* → *Order and Export* tab.
- Check the *Android Private Libraries* option.

[image: Android Private Libraries option]

Comment: Yes, you are right. I made a simple mistake. Only that now I have some problems with Eclipse and I cannot run the application. I re-started Eclipse and I am waiting to see if the problem is gone. Nevertheless I am voting up your answer. Thank you!

Comment: Now the NullPointerException is gone, but I get a problem with the NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils  which it *is* in the Referenced Libraries. Do I need to do some additional work after I added the commons-io-2.4.jar file?

Comment: Updated answer. Also make sure your jar is in the libs folder.

Comment: I have now the same jar file commons-io-2.4.jar both in the libs folder and in the Android Private Libraries. Is this a mistake? It looks like a method from this jar file does not work, because my application does not do anything after I call this method. And I don't get any error.

Comment: Not really no, eclipse will reference the jar only once, thus it will overwrite one with the other. Also for that method you can check if it has an api restriction.

Comment: Thank you Aashir. I don't find any restriction.